# How does AddRazorPages add support for MVC + views?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, razor-pages, asp.net-core-7.0

I want to use Razor Pages and "MVC with views" simultaneously.

So [I used](https://www.strathweb.com/2020/02/asp-net-core-mvc-3-x-addmvc-addmvccore-addcontrollers-and-other-bootstrapping-approaches) `services.AddRazorPages()` (which gives RazorPages and WebAPI) and then `services.AddControllersWithViews()` (which gives MVC and MVC+views).

That works.

But if I omit the latter, it also works. *Why?*

The [source shows](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/d0ca5a8d20ac50a33d5451e998a5d411a810c8d7/src/Mvc/Mvc/src/MvcServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L271) that `AddRazorPages` adds basic WebAPI support via `services.AddMvcCore()`. However I don't understand how/where mvc+views is added? I want to know whether this is expected behaviour or whether I've made a config mistake.

Comment: From .net core 3 routings split into two middleware, RoutingMiddleware, and EndpointMiddleware, in simplified terms, in start-up RoutingMiddleware retrieves all endpoints and routes and keeps it in request delegates, then authorization happens and it passes then execution. The process of View selection and generating a response happens next.

Comment: So we can say services.AddRazorPages() and services.AddControllersWithViews() has nothing to do with  view selection

Comment: To get view support one must use `AddMvc` or `AddControllersWithViews`. But if I don't add those, I still get view support. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, if you just use the AddMVCCore, it will not register the view service which will make your application not work with the view.

Like below error:

[image]

But the services.AddRazorPages will add the RazorViewEngine and it contains the View features which will make the MVC view works.

Source codes of the :

```
/// <summary>
/// Register services needed for Razor Pages.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="builder">The <see cref="IMvcCoreBuilder"/>.</param>
/// <param name="setupAction">The action to setup the <see cref="RazorPagesOptions"/>.</param>
/// <returns>The <see cref="IMvcCoreBuilder"/>.</returns>
public static IMvcCoreBuilder AddRazorPages(
    this IMvcCoreBuilder builder,
    Action<RazorPagesOptions> setupAction)
{
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(builder);
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(setupAction);

    builder.AddRazorViewEngine();

    AddRazorPagesServices(builder.Services);

    builder.Services.Configure(setupAction);

    return builder;
}
```

So if you use below codes inside the MVC application it will also work well.

```
builder.Services.AddMvcCore().AddRazorViewEngine();
```

Comment: Thanks! Where did you find that? The latest branch [shows this](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/6b7a6a94fb3ff2c004f354dbfe662644dac0ce26/src/Mvc/Mvc/src/MvcServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L288).

Comment: I use F12 to see the definition inside the Visual Studio. It's inside the  MvcServiceCollectionExtensions class if you want to search about it inside github.

Comment: Finally found it under [MvcRazorPagesMvcCoreBuilderExtensions](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/d0ca5a8d20ac50a33d5451e998a5d411a810c8d7/src/Mvc/Mvc.RazorPages/src/DependencyInjection/MvcRazorPagesMvcCoreBuilderExtensions.cs#L36). You are right, calling `AddRazorPages` automatically adds view support. Those extension methods are really confusing and poorly named. Thanks for your help!

Comment: So in my case, if I want "RazorPages" and "MVC with views", it is enough to use `AddRazorPages`.

Comment: @Ionix This tool is also a useful one for navigating layers of method calls: https://source.dot.net/

Comment: @MikeBrind I've been using source.dot.net for a few days now and it's significantly improved my developer experience. Can't thank you enough!